# Performance in linq to entity queries between linq and lambda?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a doubt in a query that it's a little bit slow and i want to know what's best for performance.

Let's present this first example:

```
var result = from tableA in context.TableA
             join tableB in context.TableB on tableA.id equals tableB.id
             where *some conditions*
             select new {
                 tableA.id,
                 tableA.name,
                 another_name = tableA.TableC.name
                 some_operation = tableB.price * tableB.TableD.some_coeficient
                 another_operation = tableB.TableE.Sum(c=> c.some_value)
             };
```

This is what i have right now (after this query i perform in another variable a `result.ToList()`.

Mi question is if would be better in levels of performance to make:

1. A query with Lambda expressions? keeping the `select new {....}`
   part.
2. A query with the `select new {....}` part after the `ToList()`?

What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Your where clause may matter a lot, if it turns into something SQL server can't find with an index, or doesn't have an index for, it can kill the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Changing it to lambda expressions will not affect performance- they will be compiled into the same SQL. I recommend using a tool like [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to help determine the SQL being generated.

You definitely want to do a `select` *before* `ToList()`ing though, as this will only select the data you need from SQL, but doing it after the `ToList()` would do it in memory.

Comment: Second the use of LinqPad, by far the fastest way to tune Linq queries.

Answer (score 2):

1. It would be exactly the same. Query expressions are basically converted to the non-query-expression equivalent.
2. You'd need to use `select new { tableA, tableB }` or something similar anyway, so that you could use both variables after `ToList`... but it would probably be *slower* as then:

   - All the fields would be pulled from the database rather than only those which are used
   - The projections (including Sum etc) would all happen *after* fetching the values from the database, rather than within the database. This is very likely to involve making more database requests, to access `tableA.TableC` etc.

You should look at the generated SQL, run it in the SQL profiler to work out what's slow, consider more indexes etc.

Comment: What's better in the query, perform the nestings on the `select new` like `tableA.TableC` or perform a `join` on the query with `TableC`?